# UTC Timestamp interpretation

Tags: parsing, time, timestamp, utc

I am searching to parse this timestamp

2011-05-18T0702:19Z0088

The first part of the string ("2011-05-18T0702:19Z") look like a [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) UTC Timestamp, but i don't understand last numbers "0088"

Did someone can tell me more about this format ?

William

Comment: What kind of system did it come from?

Comment: From [Yubico api server](http://www.yubico.com)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't make sense, since `Z` is indication of UTC time, after which no symbols are allowed in datetime. So it's actually some invalid format. 
If you sure that 'Z' corresponds to UTC you can ignore symbols after it, or, better, contact source of this format and ask them for fix.

Now, I also notices there is one more error in format, there is no colon between hours and minutes:
2011-05-18T **0702** :19Z0088